# method miner_start not implemented

Tags: httprequest, bitcoin, ethereum

I am trying to start a miner in web3 Ethereum, by calling a RPC request through node's request library.

I am getting a "miner_start method not implemented" error. What am I missing?

Comment: Any Thoughts? I am still stuck at this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "miner" API is not enabled by default through JSON RPC for security reasons. You can enable it with `--rpcapi` option:

```
geth --rpc --rpcapi "eth,miner,net,web3"
```

All available modules are: admin, eth, debug, miner, net, shh, txpool, personal, web3.

Comment: I was not aware of that. That works! Thank you Pawel.

Comment: Can we unlock an account using RPC? I tried running the command including personal in the list, but it gives the same error. Are only eth, miner, net, web3 supported?

Comment: Ok, got it. The method name is personal_unlockAccount. It works, thanks!